# Como listar um objeto json para gerar um arquivo txt e fazer o download desse arquivo via requisição ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, json, download

Tenho uma requisição ajax que envia um objeto grande. Que no console do navegador é visto assim:

```
Object {data: Array[4936], paging: Object}
```

Segue o codigo da requisição:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "gerararquivo.php",
    data: response, // é o objeto que foi debugado no console.
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(file){

    }
});
```

Dúvidas:

1 - Como ler o objeto passado pelo ajax no PHP. $_POST[????]

2 - Como varrer e listar o name de cada item data  "data.name" via php, ou seja como ficaria o código para receber o objeto que foi enviado via ajax e percorrê-lo?

3 - Como fazer com que o success do meu ajax me retorne um arquivo de texto criado dentro do "gerararquivo.php" ?

Comment: Complicado sem analisar a estrutura desse objeto, tem como você postar um exemplo desse objeto recebido via ajax?

Comment: Você está tentando recuperar o payload que lhe foi enviado  dê uma observada nessa pergunta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597052/how-to-retrieve-request-payload

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1 - como ler o objeto

O objeto enviado pelo Ajax estará disponível no $_POST como um array multi dimensional

#### 2 - como iterar o objeto é recebido

Considerando que o seguinte objeto `dados` que será enviado por POST com `jQuery.ajax()`, através da propriedade `data`.

```
var dados = {
    data: [
        {name: 'foo'}
    ,   {name: 'bar'}
    ,   {name: 'baz'}
    ]
,   paging: {
        current: 1
    ,   total: 10
    }
};
```

No servidor. Você deve iterar da seguinte maneira:

```
<?php
$dados = $_POST['data'];
// array de objetos será recebido como array multidimensional
foreach ($dados as $dado) {
  // acessando propriedade do objeto
  // dados recebidos como array
  $dado['name'];
}
$paging = $_POST['paging'];
// acessando propriedade do objeto
// objeto será recebido como array
$paging['current'];
$paging['total'];
```

#### 3 - como fazer download do arquivos

É necessário usar vários objetos de APIs HTML5 relativamente novas, então é possível que resulte em erros em navegadores antigos/desatualizados ou IE. São eles: [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) e [atributo *download* de `<a>`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'gerararquivo.php',
  data: dados,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(file) {
    var a = document.createElement('a'), blob, url;
    if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
      alert('download não suportado pelo navegador');
    } else {
      // criar "arquivo", conteúdo como array e tipo como objeto
      blob = new Blob([file], {type: 'text/plain'});
      // criar URL para arquivo criado
      url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      a.href = url;
      // atribuir nome de download do arquivo
      a.download = 'nome_de_download.txt';
      // fazer download
      a.click();
      // revogar URL criada
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
  }
});
```

É possível também armazenar o arquivo no servidor como foi sugerido nos comentários, nesse caso a preocupação deve ser com concorrência de requisições simultâneas.

Comment: Não entendi ainda como fica o recebimento do dado enviado via ajax pelo php.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo se o item `objeto.data` é um _array_ no javascript, no PHP também será, ou seja `$_POST['data']`, então é só realizar um `foreach` para percorre-lo: `foreach($_POST['data'] as $data)` e dentro do `foreach` você acessa o nome assim: `$data['name']`

Comment: Eu usei o JSON.stringfy para passar o objeto no data do ajax. No $_POST['data'] data é o nome padrão pra receber o objeto ou ele colocou so como exemplo?

Comment: não é necessário usar `JSON.stringfy` em chamadas AJAX do jQuery. `$_POST['data']` é porque do objeto JSON enviado, que tem uma propriedade `data`

Comment: Oi Joao Paulo acredito que os itens 1 do @Sanção está OK. Quanto ao item 2, SE o objetivo final for apenas enviar para download o arquivo gerado pelo PHP, você pode simplesmente fazer um redirect para o arquivo usando document.location.href="http://www.site.dominio/arquivo.ext" ou então simplesmente redirecionar para uma outra página onde você possa fazer o gerenciamento de downloads. Como o objetivo final é o download, vc não terá redirect da página, vai continuar na mesma página do request e o navegador fará o output normal. Considerando q vc queira apenas fazer download como objetivo final

Answer (score 1):

1

Tirando um exemplo de [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php

// neste caso $json seria "response"
$json = '{"foo-bar": 12345}';

$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'foo-bar'}; // 12345

?>
```

Comment: Não sei como o php recebe os dados da minha requisição ajax. No seu caso você colocou na mão.

Answer (score 1):

Simplificando a resposta para as suas perguntas:

**1 - Como ler o objeto passado pelo ajax no PHP. $_POST[????]**

```
<?php
     $data = $_POST['data'];
     $paging = $_POST['paging'];
?>
```

Você tambem pode utilizar um  pra visualizar como os dados estão chegando

**2 - Como varrer e listar o name de cada item data "data.name" via php, ou seja como ficaria o código para receber o objeto que foi enviado via ajax e percorrê-lo?**

Isso varia de acordo com o tipo dos dados. O ideal seria se você postasse o resultado de um print_r($_POST) do seu arquivo PHP.

Por exemplo, data pode ser um Array de objetos, ou um array de arrays.

No caso de array de arrays:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $d)
{
  echo $d['name'];
  echo $paging->propriedade; //Paging é um objeto... varia de acordo com as propriedades dele
}
?>
```

No caso de array de objetos:

```
<?php
    foreach($data as $d)
    {
      echo $d->name;
      echo $paging->propriedade; //Paging é um objeto... varia de acordo com as propriedades dele
    }
?>
```

**3 - Como fazer com que o success do meu ajax me retorne um arquivo de texto criado dentro do "gerararquivo.php" ?**

Existem N maneiras.

- Você pode usar o exemplo do @Sanção ( Terá problemas com alguns browsers )
- Você pode usar esta referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server ( Terá problemas com alguns browsers )
- No arquivo php gerar o arquivo e salvar num diretório,retornar o endereço desse arquivo na função success, e abrir uma nova janela apontando pro endereço onde não importa o browser, o download vai acontecer...