# Existe alguma possibilidade de realizar uma ação javascript após o fim de um download?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Possuo um link para um PDF no meu site. Gostaria que ao fim do seu download a página habilitasse outro botão.

Mas a questão é: isso é possível apenas com javascript/jquery?

Se sim, como funcionaria?

Comment: só vejo a opção de fazer o download por AJAX, sua ação pode ser executada após conclusão com sucesso da requisição, [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69786/13561) mostra como fazer o download. Lado negativo: nem todas as versões de navegadores suportam essa solução

Comment: Veja essa [resposta](http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download "Title"), pode te ajudar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa o plugin jquery chamado fileDownload, exemplo de uso:

```
//
//With jquery.fileDownload.js
//custom use with promises
//
$(document).on("click", "a.fileDownloadPromise", function () {
    $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'))
        .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
        .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });

    return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download
});
```

Baixa aqui = https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Exemplo funcionando aqui = http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

Comment: que bacana o plugin lol não conhecia