# PDF decode base64

Tags: php, pdf

Estou montando um trabalho onde preciso liberar o download do arquivo em `pdf`, porém este arquivo está salvo no banco de dados ele está em formato `base64`.

A minha ideia é fazer quando o camarada clicar em cima da linha ele fazer o `download`, do arquivo.

Tentei procurar algo porém não achei nada que sana-se minha duvida.

A minha tabela está ficando assim:

```
echo '<tr>'
    . '<td><a class="ajax-link" href="ajax/gerapdf.php?id=' . $registro->DAT_PUBLIC_DOWNL . '">' . $registro->DAT_PUBLIC_DOWNL . '</a></td>'
    . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_TITUL_DOWNL . '</td>'
    . '<td>' . $registro->TXT_EXTEN_ARQUI . '</td>'
   . '</tr>';
```

gerapdf.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='arquivo.pdf'");

include '../includes/suc_validacao.php';
include '../includes/conexao.php';

$id = !empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

$conexao = new ConexaoDatabase();

$sql = "SELECT BLO_PDFXX_ARQUI  FROM DB_EGLISE.tbl_DOWNLOADS WHERE COD_IDENT_IGREJ = :igj and DAT_PUBLIC_DOWNL = :data";

$sqlVars = array();
$sqlVars[':igj'] = $suc->getCOD_IDENT_IGREJ();
$sqlVars[':data'] = $id;

$registros = $conexao->fetch($sql, $sqlVars);

echo base64_decode($registros->BLO_PDFXX_ARQUI);
```

A saída foi está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[DOWNLOAD DO BASE64 DO PDF](https://mega.nz/#!pFMWVRAJ)

Comment: Talvez precise fazer o `base64_decode()` e depois é só formatar o cabeçalho de envio

Comment: Diretamente não tem como fazer, como no exemplo que adicionei @rray

Comment: Uma sugestão é no lugar de imprirmir o pdf, colocar o link de um arquivo php(novo) que faz a consulta na base pega o conteúdo e formata o cabeçalho para pdf.

Comment: De curiosidade, o que leva alguém a salvar coisa em base64 no DB? Vejo muita gente fazendo isso, queria entender de onde vem essa idéia estranha. Zero benefício, e desperdício de espaço.

Comment: Só faria sentido usar base64 se fosse para enviar através de um protocolo de texto... Acessar via JSON ou XML é prático assim.

Comment: A ideia é salvar em um banco, como ficaria com XML ?

Comment: O arquivo que envia o PDF está na pasta `ajax/` mas fazer [download via AJAX é complicado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/69786/13561) e eu não recomendo, um link direto para página de download vai abrir a janela de salvar o arquivo e a página atual permanece carregada. Salvar o arquivo em base 64 aumenta o tamanho em aproximadamente 33%, segundo a Wikipedia, você pode utilizar colunas [Blob](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) no banco de dados, evitando a necessidade de decodificação.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que seja melhor criar um novo arquivo php, para gerar o pdf, basicamente o conteúdo dele é uma consulta ao registro desejado, formatação correta do cabeçalho para o navegador enteder que essa saida(texto puro) é um donwload de um pdf.

No arquivo de listagem seu link deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
<a href="gerarPDF.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">DOWNLOAD</a>
```

gerarPDF.php

```
<?php
   $id = !empty($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;

   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste', 'user', 'pass');
   $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela where id = ?");
   if(!$stmt->execute(array($id))){
      print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
   }

   $item = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   header("Content-type:application/pdf");
   header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename='arquivo.pdf'");
   echo $item['BLO_PDFXX_ARQUI'];
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36779/discussion-on-answer-by-rray-pdf-decode-base64)

Comment: @rray Ainda não consegui solucionar o problema, agora ja está salvando normalmente no mysql no campo BLOB, porém ainda na visualização não está funcionando, poderia voltar a me auxiliar neste caso ?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo seu código, o php ia forçar um download, mesmo se o pdf estivesse corrompido,
acredito que o seu problema seja o "ajax-link".
Se você tentar pegar o conteúdo usando ajax, você terá a o conteúdo do pdf cru.
Remova a classe ajax-link, ponha o link direto, 
acredito que funcionará assim.